# Closed form of the limit of a sequence (weighted average)

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, binomial-coefficients

I have a sequence, which can actually be seen as Riemann-Stieltjes integration with a binomial distribution. $\rho \in (0,1)$.

$$
S_N :=∑_{n=0}^{N}ρ^{N-n}(1-ρ)^{n}\binom{N}{n}\left(\frac{n}{N}\right)^\theta
$$

Using convexity/concavity of $(n/N)^\theta$ I can show the sequence declines/increases with N. The sequence is also bounded between 0 and 1. I wonder if there is a closed form limit of this sequence.

I appreciate any thoughts on this.

Comment: What is $\large C_{N}^{n}$ ?.

Comment: Sorry, it is an old notation of $\binom{N}{n}$, I fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of
a Bernstein polynomial.

To quote wikipedia,

"If $f(x)$
is a continuous function on $[0, 1]$,
if
$$B_n(f; x)
=\sum_{k=0}^n f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right) \binom{n}{k}x^k (1-x)^{n-k}
$$
then
$\lim_{n \to \infty} B_n(f; x)
\to f(x)
$
uniformly on $[0, 1]$."

Setting
$f(x) = x^{\theta}$,
$$B_n(f, x) 
=\sum_{k=0}^n \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^{\theta} \binom{n}{k}x^k (1-x)^{n-k}
\to x^{\theta}
,$$
so $S_N \to \rho^{\theta}$
as $N \to \infty$.

Comment: Thanks. I am definitely ignorant of the Bernstein Polynomial. The proof of this convergence theorem goes exactly as @gregm pointed out. Just one correction: in my definition $x$ corresponds to $1-\rho$ thus my sequence converges to $(1-\rho)^\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

As $N$ grows large, asymptotically all of the mass in that binomial distribution is concentrated near $n=\rho N$. Therefore I assume the limit will equal $\rho^\theta$. All that would be needed to establish this rigorously would be upper bounds on $\rho^{N-n} (1-\rho)^n \binom Nn$ when $|\frac nN-\rho|\ge \epsilon$. There's probably a general convergence-of-measures theorem that would do it in one shot also.